# Share node_modules installation between sub-projects, while maintaining separate package.json files

Tags: npm, node-modules, package.json

I have the following folder structure:

```
project
├───components
│   ├───component-one
│   │       package.json
│   │
│   └───component-two
│       │   package.json
│       │
│       └───node_modules
├───node_modules
└───package.json
```

Project root `project` folder contains `package.json` and is intended to have various infrastructural modules installed (Gulp, for example, as the build is centralized).

Each component under `components` folder is eventually, after build and whatnot, is deployed somewhere to be consumed by an application - using the usual `npm install` from folder or tarball. For that reason, each component must maintain its own dependencies in its own `package.json`.

Going the trivial route, installing `node_modules` into each of the component folders would lead to a crazy amount of duplication, as there may be 100s of components, each installing *mostly* the same dependencies.

Ideally I would like to:

1. run, for example, `npm install -D <module>` in `component-one` folder
2. have `package.json` in that folder updated with the `<module>`
3. have `<module>` installed in the `project` folder

This can be achieved, to some extent, running (on Windows, in this case) `mklink /D node_modules ..\..\node_modules` from `component-one` to create a symlink.

However, symlinks are fragile and finicky, so I'd like to avoid that solution.

Is there an **npm** solution, via `npm link` or something that I am missing?

Comment: I'm actually looking to do the same thing you tried to achieve here. Have you found a solution since you post this or you just go another road? thx!

Comment: @Marc-AndreR. I haven't, unfortunately. That being said, we are looking at Docker, for dev. env setup (which is what this was all about - reduce setup time/issues, with commonly used stuff and it versions).

Comment: We are also using vagrant/docker to ease the initial setup time/issue but that doesn't reduce the size of the project on the disk. No that we care that much about the space being use, it is more a question of avoiding duplication and keeping things consistent across dependencies.. Thanks anyway for your answer, if I found something on my quest, I'll keep you posted! :)

Comment: forgot to drop the link to my own question, here you go, in case I got answers that can serve you too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737024/monolytics-repo-and-multiple-node-modules-folder/